# Adding Three20 to my project on Xcode

Tags: xcode4.2, three20

I've try to add the Three20 library to my project in manual mode how described in this link

[enter link description here](https://github.com/facebook/three20/)

Well at the point 4. I can't find the "Details" table for add the libThree20.a and libThree20Core.a

At the point 5 I can't find the "Targets" section of the sidebar.

Maybe the SDK XCODE 4.2.1 Framework is different.

How Can I add the Three20 library to a my project under XCODE 4.2.1???

Answer (score 0):

You're right, these instructions are correct for the older Xcode 3. You can find a better guide at http://three20.info/article/2011-03-10-Xcode4-Support which explains on how to use the three20 python script installer